# Blocking URLs using chrome dev tools in selenium tests

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, google-chrome-devtools

My goal is to block several URLs in Chrome headless mode. Unfortunately, URLBlacklist works fine only in the headful one. To achieve that I was trying to use SetBlockedURLs experimental feature (https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Network/#method-setBlockedURLs)

```
# Attempt to block particular URL addresses
self.driver.execute_cdp_cmd('Network.enable', {})
self.driver.execute_cdp_cmd('Network.setBlockedURLs',
                                  {"urls": ["file://*", "chrome://*"]})
```

Do you have any idea why it is not working and still Chrome is opening these ones?
I use the latest chromedriver, looks like the issue was fixed in v85 version https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/8750.

Maybe you know about any different ways to block special addresses (should work also with resources) I can use in headless mode?

Comment: Just want to verify, are you are using the `--headless=new` chrome option in selenium and not the deprecated one ? You should have full extension/capability access with new headless